# Update Table: Copy result from one row to another in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

i am facing the following problem when updating data in a table.

First the structure of the database.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 : 
Votings: Columns: PKID, RESULT, USAGE, GROUP

- For each usage a group has to vote and the result is saved in this table.

Table 2:
Usages: Columns: PKID, STATUS, SOURCE

- Each usage has a status, some usages have a source usage, but it can be null.

Now i need to migrate my data. I want to copy certain results from some votings to some other votings in the votings table.

And here i'm stuck...

The use case is the following:
Every voting with a usage in status 4 (i call it active) and group b should get the result of the voting of group b which is bound to the usage whose source is the usage in status 4 (the active usage).

These are the the results i want to insert:

```
select v2.result from votings v2
join usage us on us.pkid = v2.usage
where us.status=10 and us.source in (
    select v3.usage from votings v3
    join usage us2 on us2.pkid = v3.usage 
    where us2.status = 4 and v3.group = v2.group)
```

But now i'm not able to link these results to the correct row...
Here an example:

[example merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RA3Z.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do to other people.

Comment: i added a picture as an example. maybe it helps to explain my desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly You need `merge` similiar to this:

```
merge into votings v
using (select u2.pkid usid, vt.grp, vt.result 
         from votings vt 
         join usage   u1 on vt.usage  = u1.pkid and u1.status = 10
         join usage   u2 on u2.source = u1.pkid and u2.status =  4
        ) s
on (v.usage = s.usid and v.grp = s.grp)
when matched then update set result = s.result
```

Test data:

```
create table votings(PKID varchar2(3), RESULT int, USAGE varchar2(3), GRP varchar2(2));
insert into votings values ('V01', 23, 'U01', 'B');
insert into votings values ('V02', 17, 'U02', 'B');
insert into votings values ('V03',  9, 'U04', 'C');
insert into votings values ('V04',  3, 'U04', 'B');

create table usage (PKID varchar2(3), STATUS int, SOURCE varchar2(3));
insert into usage values ('U01', 10, null);
insert into usage values ('U02', 10, null);
insert into usage values ('U04',  4, 'U01');
```

After update value `3` for key `V04` was replaced with `23` (key `V01`).

Comment: you understood everything correctly. the only thing i had to edit was the source  
  `join usage   u2 on u2.source = u1.pkid and u2.status =  4`  
to  
   `join usage   u2 on u1.source = u2.pkid and u2.status =  4`  

i didnt know the merge command before. but it was exactly what i needed.